# Data is not getting posted from $.ajax to .Net core asp.net mvc method

Tags: c#, asp.net, reactjs

Here is my server side method (which is getting data through postman)

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpStatusCode RegisterNewUser(UserModel user)
        {
            return HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
```

Here is .jsx Code of javascript :

```
 $.ajax({
                url: "Home/RegisterNewUser",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(this.state),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (status) {
                    console.log(status);
                    if (status == '200') {
                        alert('You are registered now !!');
                        this.setState({ Email: '', FirstName: '', LastName: '', LastNamePrefix: '', AcceptTerms: false, CompanyName: '' });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(' you are not registered !!');
                    }
                    $('#forgetEmailId').val('');
                    $('#divGetPass').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#getPass').val('Send My Password on Email');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Some error occured !!');
                }
            });
```

THis javascript code is hitting the debug pointer inside my server side method but the Model is not getting populated , while If I am hitting it using Postman then the Model is populated.

Here is full react code

```
var RegistrationBox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {Email:'', FirstName: '', LastName: '',LastNamePrefix:'',AcceptTerms:false,CompanyName:'' };
    },
    handleEmailChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({Email: e.target.value });
    },
    handleFirstNameChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ FirstName: e.target.value });
    },
    handleLastNamePrefixChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ LastNamePrefix: e.target.value });
    },
    handleLastNameChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ LastName: e.target.value });
    },
    handleCompanyNameChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ CompanyName: e.target.value });
    },
    handleAcceptChange: function (e) {
        this.setState({ AcceptTerms: e.target.checked });
    },
    toggleIsChecked: function () {
        this.setState({ AcceptTerms: !this.state.checked });
    },
    handleReset: function (e) {
        this.setState({ Email:'', FirstName: '', LastName: '', LastNamePrefix: '', AcceptTerms: false, CompanyName: '' });
    },
    handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var email = this.state.Email.trim();
        var fName = this.state.FirstName.trim();
        var lName = this.state.LastName.trim();
        var lNamePrefix = this.state.LastNamePrefix.trim();
        var cName = this.state.CompanyName.trim();
        var aTerms = this.state.AcceptTerms;

        if (email == null || fName == null || lName == null ||
            lNamePrefix == null || cName == null || aTerms == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (aTerms == false){
            alert('Please accept Terms');
            return;
        }
        else //Make Ajax Call
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Home/RegisterNewUser",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(this.state),
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (status) {
                    console.log(status);
                    if (status == '200') {
                        alert('You are registered now !!');
                        this.setState({ Email: '', FirstName: '', LastName: '', LastNamePrefix: '', AcceptTerms: false, CompanyName: '' });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert(' you are not registered !!');
                    }
                    $('#forgetEmailId').val('');
                    $('#divGetPass').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#getPass').val('Send My Password on Email');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('Some error occured !!');
                }
            });
        }
    },

    render: function () {
        var chkBoxStyle = {
            width: 25,
            height: 25,
        };

        var chkboxlabel = {
            margin: 8
        };

        return (
            <div className="registrationBox">
                <form method="post" id="user-registration-form" data-parsley-validate className="form-horizontal form-label-left">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            Email <span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.handleEmailChange} value={this.state.Email} type="text" id="email" required="required" className="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            First Name <span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange} value={this.state.FirstName} type="text" id="first-name" required="required" className="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            Last Name Prefix<span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.handleLastNamePrefixChange} value={this.state.LastNamePrefix} type="text" id="last-name-prefix" name="last-name-prefix" required="required" className="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            Last Name <span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.handleLastNameChange} value={this.state.LastName} type="text" id="last-name" name="last-name" required="required" className="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label
                            style={chkboxlabel}
                            className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            Accept Terms & Conditions &nbsp;
                            <span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="checkbox col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div style={{ float: 'left', width: 60, paddingLeft: 5 }}>
                                <input onChange={this.handleAcceptChange} checked={this.state.AcceptTerms} type="checkbox" id="accept"
                                    name="accept" required="required" style={chkBoxStyle} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label className="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            Company Name <span className="required">*</span>
                        </label>
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <input onChange={this.handleCompanyNameChange} value={this.state.CompanyName} type="text" id="company-name" name="compnay-name" required="required" className="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary" type="button">Cancel</button>
                            <button onClick={this.handleReset} className="btn btn-primary" type="reset">Reset</button>
                            <button onClick={this.handleSubmit} type="button" className="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <RegistrationBox />,
    document.getElementById('registration-div')
);
```

this line
JSON.stringify(this.state)
is giving everything as expected.

Looks like I missed something really small but important.. :(
[image]

**User Model**
**

```
public class UserModel
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastNamePrefix { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool AcceptTerms { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

**

while using Postman such POST request is working fine with same serverside code
[image]

Comment: Can we see your client side model (or form)?

Comment: updated Code and screenshot as well @JoePhillips

Comment: Show UserModel as well

Comment: url: Home/RegisterNewUser -> url:  localhost:51251/Home/RegisterNewUser

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(this.state)` - why are you stringifying the model? This shouldn't be necessary. The likelihood is you're passing one single string parameter to the server, which happens to look like JSON, but is treated as one single string (rather than an object with multiple properties). You can verify this by looking in your browser's network tab to see what's in the request body, but I'm pretty sure if you just do `data: this.state`, or maybe `data: { user: this.state}` (depending exactly how `this.state` is structured) it should work.

Comment: Ok let me try this @ADyson